# Get the output SQL from a Liquibase changeset

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm having a SQL syntax error when my Spring Boot application tries to start. It cannot instantiate the SpringLiquibase bean, because the outputed SQL of a changeset is leading to a syntax error. I need to check the SQL generated from Liquibase in order to find what's wrong. How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try `liquibase updateSQL` command

- http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html
- http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/update.html